# Can I use just HTML and CSS to make a contact form?

Tags: html, css

So I was creating a contact form and realized that I am not sure how to connect the submit button to send it to a set email. Is HTML and CSS enough to do this or do I need a database, storage, or different language? If so which one would be the easiest to learn and do? Here is my code if you need it.

```css
     body {
          background: #292a2b;
          font-family: Arial;
        }
        
        .contact-title {
          margin: auto;
          width: 30%;
          border: 1.5px solid #0054a9;
          padding: 5px 0px;
          border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
          background: #0054a9;
        }
        
        .contact-title h2 {
          text-align: center;
          color: #ede;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        
        .name-contact {
          margin: auto;
          width: 30%;
          padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
          background: #fff;
        }
        
        .message-contact {
          margin: auto;
          width: 30%;
          padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
          background: #fff;
        }
        
        .box-size {
          margin-left: 5%;
          width: 90%;
          height: 40px;
          font-size: 18px;
          border: 0px;
          border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
        }
        
        .submit-size {
          margin-left: 5%;
          width: 90%;
          height: 50px;
          font-size: 18px;
          border: 0px;
        }
        textarea {
          font-family: inherit;
          font-size: inherit;
          height: 2px;
        }
        
        .submit-contact {
          margin: auto;
          width: 30%;
          padding: 15px 0px 55px 0px;
          border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
          background: #fff;
        }
        
        h3 {
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 8px;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          color: #fff;
          background: #0054a9;
          margin-left: 38%;
          margin-right: 38%;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
        
        .sub-btn {
          height: 40%;
          width: 20%;
        }
```

```html
    <section class="contact">
        <div class="contact-title">
            <h2> CONTACT </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="name-contact">
            <label for="Name"></label>
            <input class="box-size" type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="name-contact">
            <label for="Email"></label>
            <input class="box-size" type="text" id="femail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="message-contact">
            <label for="Message"></label>
            <textarea class="box-size" type="text" id="fmessage" name="message"  placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-contact submit-size">
            <h3 class="sub-btn">Submit</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
```

UPDATE: If anyone wants the HTML/CSS for the contact form, the update version is on my codepen
https://codepen.io/GabeZacarias/full/KvwqRW/

Comment: Yes you need to use `php`  and `database`

Comment: Nope... Just HTML and CSS won't be enough to send an email.. You'll need a server side programming language like `php`, `java`, `c#`, etc. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/) is a tutorial that shows you how to integrate phpmailer in your contact form.

Comment: You need something to process that form. Either save it to a db, email it, something...

Comment: You need serverside code that will deliver the information of the form to the recipient.

Comment: how do you expect a markup language to speak to the server?

Comment: check out these https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/free-contact-form-services/

Comment: You need to use php first if you want to mail. And if you want to store the user information for further use you need to store it in a databse.

Comment: You don't need a database, you can store the info in a json file

Comment: @Kangouroops — The question is about sending email, not storing data locally.

Comment: @Quentin , I know, It was a response to Ankit Singh and Peter Haddad, I should have mentionned them in my first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a server side language. Any server side language at all.

Which one you choose will be a matter of preference and a trade off between what your web server already supports and how much effort it would be to add support for what you want or to change server.

Write a server side program to read the form data and send the email. Specify the URL to that program in the `action` attribute of the form element.

---

You could also look for a third party service which will provide you with a prewritten program and hosting for it.

Comment: Can I use Javascript (Node.Js)??

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Which server side does github pages support?

Comment: AFAIK. None. It only provides static content hosting.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty solution you could use Google Forms connected to a Google Sheet. Here's a video showing how to accomplish this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiGCFE5KyoQ.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you will need both HTML, CSS, and PHP. The PHP can then forward the responses to an Email. There are plenty of tutorials for that.

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form, yes you need php and some sort of back end to hold the data.

If you just want to have the browser open the users local email client with your address and subject pre-populated you can just use an email link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Note you can't have spaces, you need to use %20.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need something server side to process the form. Email submit is also an option if it suits your needs, but people might find it annoying when you force them to open an email agent.

You could try this service: http://kontactr.com/ used for my own stuff. easy to set up on a blogger site for example.